# How to get more information out of my loaded keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

Currently I work at optimizing my neural network that I trained with keras. For this, played with several activation functions within the layers and I save the models automatically with `model.save()` and do an evaluation.

Unfortunately, I forgot the exact setup of my best performing network, but **how can I recreate all network information from keras?** Of course, I use `model.load()` and there is helpful `model.summary()`. But how would I get the **activation functions**, that were used?

`model.summary()` just provides information about the network architecture itself:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
...                             ...                     ...
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 64)                288064    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 128)               8320      
=================================================================
Total params: 586,408
Trainable params: 586,408
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get read layers with `model.layers` and then use that for finding the weights or activation functions. For example

`act_fncs = [l.activation for l in model.layers]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `model.layers[id].get_config()`, where id is the index of layer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using `model.to_json()`

You can get a full copy of your model's architecture in one line using `model.to_json()`

This will give you details on layer architecture, input shape, compiler config, etc.

**Usage**

```py
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)

print(model.to_json())
```